# how to separate text lines in python

Tags: python, list, text

I am trying to split diffrent lines of text in python. I tried to use the split function and it dosent work for what I want. here is an example.
`

```
list = open(file,"r")
for Password in passlist:
       print(list)
```

`

and I want it to give this output:
`number 1`
and
`number 2`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you have saved the Passwords in your File but if you would like to open the passwords you could do something like this:

```
passlist = open("file" ,"r")
x = passlist.read().split(", ") <--- change to the format you use to save the passwords 
print(x)
```

then you could assign password1 and 2 as follows:

```
password1 = x[0]
password2 = x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean but I can guess that you want it like this?

Password 1

Password 2

If that's it then you could use this:

```
With open("file", "r") as f:
        contents=f.read()
        print(contents)
```